# I disabled loading images in chrome while using webdriver with selenium now cant enable it

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, webdriver, chrome-options

I disabled loading images in chrome while using webdriver with selenium now cant enable it.

I was using python to webscrape on instagram so thought it would be a good idea to disable images.

The commands i used:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu=true")
options.add_argument("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false")
```

And now I cannot change it from chrome settings.

[Screenshot of chrome settings page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FpZ1.png)

Please Help.

Edit: This happens only in my default Chrome Profile. Other Profiles work fine even though the profile I use for selenium is a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long day on google finally found the solution.

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images': 1})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).